# 3d graphics implementation using images in using webgl,html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, kineticjs

I'm new to HTML5 and have got one project in HTML5 canvas.
I still have to analyze the requirement.
I'm done with almost every part, the problem I'm stuck at is:

Is it possible to make a 3d out of some images formed after drag and drop and then combining them together using `webgl` or maybe `three.js` and `kinetic.js`? 
For example in this site: http://headstonesandmemorials.com/pillow/pillow_hickey_bevel_headstone_designer.php

Is it possible to first fully design a headstone using pre loaded images and then making a 3d view out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use javascript / CSS 3D transforms to combine the images into 3d shapes without needing to use WebGL theres a nice tutorial here:

http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html

Comment: And ya i forgot in 3d view the user should be able to rotate it and look around..